# Como identificar se um pacote npm é thread blocking ou não?

Tags: node.js, thread, npm

Estou usando o pacote [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) em um projeto em `node.js`.
Gostaria de saber se esse pacote bloqueia o event loop e como eu poderia identificar pacotes que sejam thread-bloking ou não.

Comment: Eu não conheço nenhuma ferramenta do node ou do npm que automatize isso. Você vai precisar analisar o pacote, testar se ele bloqueia ou não - até porque toda biblioteca pode ter diversas funções sendo que uma pode ser bloqueante, mas outra não.

Comment: Votei para fechar essa pergunta por ela ser muito ampla - não consigo imaginar uma resposta que seja satisfatória.